# Removing elements from a collection

Tags: java, collections

I want to remove elements from more than one collection in an other collection. Is there a single method that take a collection of collection of elements and removes all of them.

```
Collection<String> coll1;
Collection<String> coll2;
Collection<String> coll3;
Collection<String> mainCollection;

mainCollection.removeAll(coll1);
mainCollection.removeAll(coll2);
mainCollection.removeAll(coll3);
```

I don't like to call removeAll on each collection seperately. Is there a single method that does it.

Comment: No, but you could write one.

Comment: *"Is there a single method that take a collection of collection of elements and removes all of them."* Well, [is there](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#method.summary)?

Comment: This is such a non issue. Add the `Collection<String>`s to a `Collection<Collection<String>>` and loop through it, using each element to `removeAll`.

Comment: And why not a method that takes a collection of collections of collections?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't a single method of that sort. You'll have to call it on each Collection in order to clear it.
Browse through the following link for further information. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in method, but you can easily write one.

Java 7:

```
<E> void removeAllOf(Collection<E> removeFrom, Collection<E>... toRemove) {
    for (Collection<E> remove : toRemove) {
        removeFrom.removeAll(remove);
    }
}
```

Java 8:

```
<E> void removeAllOf(Collection<E> removeFrom, Collection<E>... toRemove) {
    Arrays.stream(toRemove).forEach(removeFrom::removeAll);
}
```

Then, simply:

```
removeAllOf(mainCollection, coll1, coll2, coll3);
```